# Generate a row of a modified Pascal's triangle.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, triangles

The traditional Pascal's triangle grows by a width of 1 (**N=1**) each row. I have a modified Pascal's triangle that grows by a width of **N** each row. Where you sum the **N+1** numbers symmetrically above a position in a generated row. The starting row contains (**N+1**) ones.

*I am only concerned about when **N** is odd such that you can sum above easily. I haven't thought much about when **N** is even.*

Example with **N=3** and **rows=4**:

```
              1 1 1 1
           1 2 3 4 3 2 1
      1 3 6 10 12 12 10 6 3 1
1 4 10 20 31 40 44 40 31 20 10 4 1
```

Example with **N=5** and **rows=3**:

```
               1 1 1 1 1 1
          1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 3 6 10 15 21 25 27 27 25 21 15 10 6 3 1
```

This type of modified pascal's triangle is useful for calculating the probability of the *sum of rolling **R** dice with **(N+1)** faces.*

The only way I can figure out how to generate **row R** is generate **row R-1** which requires me to generate the entire triangle from the top. In the traditional pascal's triangle there is [a shortcut to generate a row in linear time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154955/is-there-an-equation-that-represents-the-nth-row-in-pascals-triangle). But I cannot seem to figure one out for this modified triangle.

If this is confusing or needs more context or another example just comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have better start with the Pascal Triangle in the version having the leftmost elements aligned.
And you have better to consider the full triangle starting with $\binom{n}{m} =\binom {0}{0}$, and consider null all
the elements to the left of the column $m=0$.

Then in this version, the triangle is constructed by summing two elements from the line immediately above,
starting from the element immediately above $\binom {n-1}{m}$ and proceeding to the left.
In your case instead you will sum $r$ elements, whether $r$ is odd or even.

You will discover that your elements are the (somebody call them *r-nomials*) coefficients of
$$(1+x+x^2+ \cdots+ x^{r-1})^n=((1-x^r)/(1-x))^n$$.

Then take a look at [e.g. this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A008287).

After that take a look at [this other related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420) , and to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045496/number-of-occurrences-of-k-consecutive-1s-in-a-binary-string-of-length-n-) to get a closed sum expression for the numbers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have each row of your "triangle" being the coefficients of $\,P^n\,$ where $\,P\,$ is the polynomial whose coefficients are the first row. In the usual Pascal's triangle, $\,P := 1 + x.\,$ In your first example with $\,N = 3\,$ the polynomial $\,P = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3.\,$ In this special case, $\, P = (1 - x^4) / (1 - x).\,$ Thus, $\, P^n = (1 - x^4)^n  (1 - x)^{-n}.\,$ Using binomial coefficients we have $\, (1 - x^4)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{4k}.$ Also,
$ (1 - x)^{-n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k {n-k+k \choose k}. \,$ Convolve these two power series to get your $\,P^n.\,$ Of course, there are the [Multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) but I don't see how they would be better to use in this case.