# Find Pascal's Triangle Nth row Xth element

Tags: binomial-coefficients

```
row 1 |     1
row 2 |    1 1   
row 3 |   1 2 1
row 4 |  1 3 3 1
row 5 | 1 4 6 4 1
```

I recently made a computer program that involved Pascal's Triangles.

However I got obsessed with optimizing it.

I know there is a way to get Nth row / Xth element of the triangle. However any formulas I tried (including from math stack exchange) did not worked.

What I want is for example to have 5th row, 2nd element and result to be `4`.

Because most of other similar answers did not really work, will be glad, if you give me the answer as a function in some programming language.
Let suppose we have function `long factorial(long x)` already done.

Thanks.

References that does not work:

- [Is there an equation that represents the nth row in Pascal's triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154955/is-there-an-equation-that-represents-the-nth-row-in-pascals-triangle)

Comment: ${N-1} \choose {X-1}$ will work because generally it is $N \choose X$ where $N$ starts from $0$ and $X$ takes values from $0$ to $N$ but your desired index starts from $1$ instead of $0$.

Comment: can you write it as formula with factorial ! . also let me know what index is from 0 and what from 1

Comment: You can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) for the definition. What I am saying is if you reindex your rows from $0$ to $4$ or start counting from $0$ then the $x$  th ($x$ starts from $0$) element in $n$ th row is $n \choose x$

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. I suppose other example add / subtracts 1's.

Answer (score 0):

With help from @Infinity_hunter and Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Example is in `C++` but can be rewritten in `C`, `Java`, `PHP`, `nodejs` very easy:

```
#include <cstdio>

long factoriel(int x){
    long result = 1;

    if (x == 0 || x == 1)
        return result;

    for(int i = 2; i <= x; ++i)
        result = result * i;

    return result;
}

long pascal_triangle_nth(int row, int x){
    --row;
    --x;

    return factoriel(row) / ( factoriel(row - x) * factoriel(x) );
}


int main(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i){
        printf("%d >>>> ", i);

        for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
            printf(" %ld ", pascal_triangle_nth(i, j));

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1 >>>>  1 
2 >>>>  1  1 
3 >>>>  1  2  1 
4 >>>>  1  3  3  1 
5 >>>>  1  4  6  4  1 
6 >>>>  1  5  10  10  5  1 
7 >>>>  1  6  15  20  15  6  1 
8 >>>>  1  7  21  35  35  21  7  1 
9 >>>>  1  8  28  56  70  56  28  8  1
```